# Chaining of array promises in Axios

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, axios

I have an array of requests that I need to make with `Axios` sequentially.

```
let {files} = this.state, requestQueue = [];
files.forEach(file => requestQueue.push(makeRequest(file.name)));
requestQueue.reduce((curr, next) => {
  return curr.then(next);
}, Promise.resolve()).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

function makeRequest is as below

```
import Axios from 'axios';

let axiosCustom = Axios.create({
  baseUrl: 'localhost:8080',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json'
  }
});

const makeRequest = (title) => {
  return axiosCustom({
    url: '/api',
    method: 'PUT',
    params: {
      title
    }
  });
};
```

The response is just the first one resolved. How do I fix this?

Comment: Actually you will need to use `requestQueue.push(() => makeRequest(file.name)))` for this to work

Comment: @Bergi That would delegate creation of the promise but should have the same behavior in terms of the reduce as mine. You create a method which returns a promise, i have an array of promises and pass the `then` a method which returns the promise. Unless I'm missing something, the only difference is when the promise executes?

Comment: @ste2425: Yes, that's the difference. But the OP said he wanted them to execute sequentially… As it stands, he could just have used `Promise.all(requestQueue)`

Comment: @Bergi ahh ok, always like to ask incase I missed something in an effort to learn. I thought the OP meant sequentially in serial which is why I kept the reduce, but that would execute them sequentially in parallel so all good.

Comment: I meant sequentially in sequence, first promise resolves and then starts the second. Promise.all will run them asynchronously. Apologies if it was ambiguous. P1 executes and resolves, P2 starts and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you chain axios using array synchronously.

```
const axios = require('axios');
function makeRequestsFromArray(arr) {
    let index = 0;
    function request() {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/' + index).then(() => {
            index++;
            if (index >= arr.length) {
                return 'done'
            }
            return request();
        });

    }
    return request();
}

makeRequestsFromArray([0, 1, 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is `.then()` requires a function to execute. Its behaviour will change depending on the return value of that function (if its `thenable`).

So you need to change your reduce to provide `.then` with a method that will return `next`:

```
let {files} = this.state,
    requestQueue = files.map(file => makeRequest(file.name));

requestQueue.reduce((curr, next) => {
  return curr.then(() => next); // <- here
}, Promise.resolve())
    .then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Or

```
requestQueue.reduce((curr, next) => curr.then(() => next), Promise.resolve())
    .then((res) => console.log(res));
```